# if else statement in Razor is not functioning

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, if-statement

I am using an if else in Razor view to check for null value like this:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr id="@(item.ShopListID)">
            <td class="shoptablename">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td class="shoptableamount">
                @if (item.Amount == null)
                {
                    Html.Display("--");
                }
                else
                {
                    String.Format("{0:0.##}", item.Amount);
                }
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
```

However, no matter my model amount is null or having a value, the html rendered do not contain any value in the amount.

I wonder why this is happening. Any idea?

Thanks...

EDIT:

Decided to did it in controller:

```
   // Function to return shop list food item amount
    public string GetItemAmount(int fid)
    {
        string output = "";

        // Select the item based on shoplistfoodid
        var shopListFood = dbEntities.SHOPLISTFOODs.Single(s => s.ShopListFoodID == fid);

        if (shopListFood.Amount == null)
        {
            output = "--";
        }
        else
        {
            output = String.Format("{0:0.##}", shopListFood.Amount);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

and call at View like:

```
 <td class="shoptableamount">
                @Html.Action("GetItemAmount", "Shop", new { fid = item.ShopListFoodID })
            </td>
```

Comment: You would have to show us what the Model itself looks like, specifically the Model.Amount field. Maybe try @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Amount) instead?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, but the amount is a decimal and if i follow the one u stated here, it didnt work. anyway, please refer to my edit because I decide to did it in controller. Thank you :)

Comment: If else combination indeed does not work in razor.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You have to use the `@()`

```
            @if (item.Amount == null)
            {
                @("--");
            }
            else
            {
                @String.Format("{0:0.##}", item.Amount)
            }
```

As noted in the comments and other answers, the `Html.Display` is not for displaying strings, but for displaying data from the `ViewData` Dictionary or from a `Model`. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310174%28v=VS.98%29.aspx#Y0

Comment: Your answer works if i do this in razor: @if (item.Amount == null)
                {
                    @Html.Display("--")
                }
But I cant get the null check works, so i decided to do it in controller instead. Thanks!

Comment: @shennyL check out my answer and dotnetstep's answer.  I don't think the `Display()` method is doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @shennyL, as @Shark points out, besides the missing `@` for actually outputting something, the `Html.Display` was not doing what you thought it was..

Answer (score 6):

I think you want to display "-----" if amount is null.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr id="@(item.ShopListID)">
            <td class="shoptablename">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td class="shoptableamount">
                @if (item.Amount == null)
                {
                    @Html.Raw("--")
                }
                else
                {
                    String.Format("{0:0.##}", item.Amount);
                }
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using the `Display()` method incorrectly.  The overload you are using is [`Display(HtmlHelper, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee310174.aspx).  If you are looking for "--" to be the text, you should use something like:

```
@Html.Label("--");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two other ways to display text from a code block in razor besides the suggested @(""), using a <text> tag and it's shorthand @:

```
    @{
        @("--")
        <text>--</text>
        @:--
    }
```

The code above will display -- three times.