# How to use C# inside an html tag in a razor view?

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to hide an html row using inline css and C# conditionals and I am not getting the syntax correctly.  (I know how to hide the row using jQuery but I want to use inline css)

My try: `<tr @{if (Model.Loan.IsValid != "Y") {@:style="display:None;"}}>`

Another try: `<tr @(Model.Loan.IsValid != "Y"? "style=display: None;":"")>` shows as `<tr style="display:" none;="">`

Comment: Is there a reason you can't nest the HTML inside the if rather than putting the if inside the tr?

Comment: I've only just *started* to look at Razor the past week or so, but based on [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8549471/1189566) couldn't you do something like `@if (Model.Loan.IsValid != "Y") @("<tr ...>");`? Basically just encase the HTML within the razor snippet. I feel like your question is backwards; it's more like how to use HTML in a razor tag / view than how to use C# inside HTML.

Comment: I suppose I could but using my way it's more concise. Everything is in one line without wrapping html with anything.

Comment: What good is more concise if you can't get it to work? :) Shorter != Better

Comment: It didn't work. That's why I posted here. So I learn how to do it right.  Shorter can mean simpler. KISS. The TR could be spanning tens of lines and then you have to find the closing brace by scrolling down using your way. Put the condition inside the tag with an expression.  What if I want to make the background yellow based on a condition? It's still the same coding style using css. Your wrapper style won't work. So no.. I am not thinking backwards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way. Using the @: breaks out of the C# code so you can start using HTML in the middle of the C# statement.

```
<tr 
    @if(Model.Loan.IsValid != "Y") 
    {
        @:style="display:none;"
    }
>

<tr>
```

Comment: What were the errors? I didn't get any errors when I ran it.

Comment: I had it in one line and it gave errors. Yes it works when I have it like yours in multiple lines. Not sure why this matters.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<tr @(Html.Raw(Model.Loan.IsValid != "Y"? "style=\"display: None;\"":""))>
```

Edit: I would suggest to use a class instead of a style however

Comment: Yours works but I selected the easier to read answer. Thanks.

Comment: I was trying to stick with the spirit of the style the question was asked in. I would actually not do either and not output the tag (row in this case) to the client in the first place unless there was a need to update it back to being displayed, but not knowing the entire use case it is always difficult to provide perfect answers. If you are indeed not needing to flip it back to visible remove it as it saves a few bytes in transfer and increases display performance (albeit marginally so).

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this in one line is using a variable as follow:

```
<tr style="display: @{ var display = (Model.Loan.IsValid != "Y") ? "none" : ""; @display; }">  
</tr>
```

Rei.

Comment: beste answer for me

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're attempting to do the following:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(content => 
      Model.Loan.IsValid != "Y" ? "<tr style="display: none;"></tr>" : "<tr></tr>");
```

If you're attempting to be concise with a single line.  A ternary, would work ideal in that instance.  I used `DisplayFor`, but it might not be ideal based on your model, without more information.  The `Raw` may be better.